# matlab quadprog constraints issue

Tags: matlab, optimization, quadprog

I have a portfolio of weights I am using quadprog in matlab. 
I have all the inputs for the quadprog optimizer. I am just having some trouble formulating
the constraints

I would like my constraints to have a lower bound of either 0 or 1%, is there a way to do that while maintainng my objective function

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question well.

If your weights are already defined in terms of percentage, it is directly the definition of `quadprog`:

```
x = quadprog(H, f, [], [], [], [], lb, [])
```

So `H`, `e`, and `f` should be provided by the matlab description of:

> **`quadprog(H,f)`** - returns a vector `x` that minimizes `1/2 * x' * H * x + f' * x`. `H` must be positive definite for the problem to have a finite minimum."

And `lb` is a vector of the constraints. For instance if `x` is a vector `3 x 1`, then `lb = [0.01; 0.01; 0.01]` in the case of the desired percentage is `0.01` (`1%`)

On the other hand, lets assume the `sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i` is not equal to `1`. Therefore, `w_i` is not defined in terms of percentage.

Therefore, the constraint that you need is `p_i (percentage)= w_i / (sum w_i) >= 0.01` (in the case of the lower bound be `1%`).

Note that the constraint in this case is

`w_i >= 0.01 * (sum w_i)`

Or

`-0.01 * (sum_{j=1}^{i-1} w_j) + 0.99 * w_i - 0.01 * (sum_{j=i+1}^{n} w_j) >= 0`

Or

`0.01 * (sum_{j=1}^{i-1} w_j) - 0.99 w_i + 0.01 * (sum_{j=i+1}^{n} w_j) <= 0`

Therefore, this is a constraint of the type `Ax <= b`.

So

`A_ij = 0.01` when `i` is different from `j`

`A_ij = -0.99` when `i = j` and `b = zeros(n, 1)`

In this case you are using

```
x = quadprog(H, f, A, b)
```

I hope I helped you!

Daniel

Comment: Hi Daniel, I am trying to set the minimum to be either 1% or 0 nothing in between..Thats what I am struggling with

Comment: @hdg I am not understanding what u want or you are not understanding my solution above. Considere the case that all the weights are larger than 2% for instance. In this case, the constrained and the unconstrained problem have the same solutions. Now imagine the situation that the unconstrained problem has a weight equal to 0.5% and your constraint is 1%. So the unconstrained solution is not acceptable. So the constrained problem should consider the constraints presented above. I am not assuming that the lower bound is a number between 0 and 1%. If you have doubts about above, just ask!

Comment: @hdg (continuation) Above I am assuming that either the weights are unconstrained or they are larger than 1% or larger than 0%; I am NOT assuming that they are larger than 0.5% for instance.